# Redirect wi-fi to a proxy

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, wifi-hotspot

i have a such following LAN: there is a PC that running proxy server on it. My Android phone is on that line. my wi-fi hotspot is on. i want to redirect my wi-fi to proxy? is it possible?
my phone is: Android 4.4 Samsung Galaxy S4 mini

Answer (score 0):

Each Wi-Fi network has settings in it. There's an "Advanced settings" option there ( I can't say how exactly it's called on 4.4 as I have only 5.x devices now). In Advanced settings you can specify a proxy address for this connection. Note, that the browser settings can be different from the proxy you configure in network settings.